# What is the difference between "till" and "until"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, word-usage, till-until

What is the difference between *till* and *until*?

When to use *till* or *until*? Please explain with examples.

Comment: In a nutshell, they can be used interchangeably in most situations, with the obvious exception of fixed phrases such as "Till death do us part". Some people will object to "till" (as being too informal or whatever), but only for entirely made-up reasons (such as that "till" is a careless abbreviation of "until" or something, which is simply wrong; "till" is actually the older of the two words, and "until" was derived from it rather than the other way round).

Comment: @RegDwigнt cool, learned something new.  I was, until now, one of those that that till was just a truncated until.

Comment: I guess they are historically related like *to* and *unto*?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

@RegDwight is correct in every particular. *Till* is indeed older and the two can be used pretty much interchangeably.

There is really only one usage I can think of where you would not use *till*: in setting up a negative conditional.

> Until my landlord fixes the plumbing,
>   I am not going to pay the rent.
>
> I am not going to pay the rent until
>   my landlord fixes the plumbing.

Here it would sound strange to use *till*, and I'm not really sure why. Perhaps it is the negative.

One more thing. Sometimes you will see people spell *till* as a contraction of *until*: that is, as *'til*. This is simply wrong, and not seen outside of old poetry and modern greeting cards aiming for a "poetic" tone. Anywhere you see *'til* being used, *till* would be the correct word.

Comment: +1 for "RegDwight is correct in every particular" (^_^). Seriously though, +1 for the rest as well. (See e.g. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/'til) marking "'til " as nonstandard, saying "Those unaware of ['till' being older than 'until'] sometimes assume that *till* is a short form of *until* and hence spell it as *'til*. This word is nonstandard but in widespread use.")

Comment: I don't think it's the negative, but simply flow - note that "It ain't over till the fat lady sings" is fine.  However, "rent till" is harder to parse than "rent until", and also harder to say due to the double 't'.

Comment: I don't find "till" strange in that sentence.  Am I the only one?

Comment: @Kosmonaut: The second example would sound less strange using *till* but I really can't wrap my ear around that usage in the first. Perhaps it's a regional thing.

Comment: I wonder if it's an association with "unless" ("Unless my landlord fixes the plumbing...")?

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道 *til* / *'til* vs *till* has become somewhat of an AE vs BE thing. *Til* and *'til* are common in the US. Till to me is a cash drawer or a verb meaning to plow. BTW, if you're going by older forms, *til* is older than *till*.

Comment: @AnWulf: "Interestingly, while it is commonly assumed that till is an abbreviated form of until (the spellings 'till and 'til reflect this), till is in fact the earlier form." (NOAD) While OE *til* is older than *till*, *till* is older than *until*. And although *'til* is seen in the U.S. sometimes, nobody but an illiterate deliberately writes *til*.

Comment: @Robusto - Til was noted in ME and has been in continuous since then as well.

2010 May, Parker, James, “Revenge of the Wimps”, The Atlantic Monthly, volume 305, number 4, page 38: 
EVEN IF YOU MAKE ME WRITE IN THIS EVERY DAY TIL THEY LET ME OUT OF HERE ...

Comment: What about "I will not leave home until the TV show ends" vs "I will not leave home till the TV show is running"? Both seem to have the same meaning. However, "till" is referring to something that is ongoing or continuous while "until" refers to a momentary event.

Comment: In hiberno-english they can be used completely interchangeably, in fact where I grew up "till" was used almost exclusively.

Comment: till be more continuous, until for expecting anticipation for possibility of an upcoming

Answer (score 32):

### Usage

According to the usage notes from the [entry for *till* in dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/till), *until* and *till* are interchangeable:

> *Till* and *until*  are both old in the
> language and are interchangeable as
> both prepositions and conjunctions:
>
> *It rained till  (or until ) nearly midnight.*
>
> *The savannah remained brown and lifeless until  (or till ) the rains began.*
>
> Till  is not a shortened
> form of until  and is not spelled
> 'till. 'Til  is usually considered a
> spelling error, though widely used in
> advertising: *Open 'til ten.*

### Etymology

According to the entries for *[till](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=till)* and *[until](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=until)* in the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com), *until* would have derived from *till*:

*until* = *und* + *till*,
where *und* was an Old English word meaning "as far as, up to".

> **till**  O.E. *til* (Northumbrian), from O.N. *til* from P.Gmc. **tilan*
> (..) A common preposition in
> Scandinavian, probably originally the
> accusative case of a noun now lost
> except for Icelandic *tili* (..) the
> noun used to express aim, direction,
> purpose.
>
> **until**
> c.1200, from O.N. und "as far as, up to" (related to O.E. end; see end)
>
> - till "until, up to" (see *till*). Originally also used of persons and
>   places. Cf. Swed. intill, Dan. indtil.
>   The Mod.Ger. equivalent, bis (O.H.G.
>   biaz), is a similar compound, of
>   O.H.G. bi "by, at, to" and zu "to

### Frequency

[Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

```
until = 176K occurrences
till = 11K occurrences
```

[British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

```
until = 39K occurrences
till = 5K occurrences
```

Comment: Wow so both *till* and *until* were borrowings from Old Norse into Old English. I wonder what was used before the borrowing?

Answer (score 20):

It's been [suggested](http://web.archive.org/web/20130520104740/http://contentcaramel.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/till-and-until-are-different/) that there's a difference in aspect: *till* is used with continuous actions, while *until* is used for perfective.  However, this is not supported by any references or general usage, and seems to be an independent analysis.

The only difference is that *until* has no homophones. I'd suggest using *until* whenever there's a risk of confusion or difficulty in pronunciation, and only use *till* where it's suitable for the flow.  *Till*, being older and ambiguous is often used poetically ("till death do us part") which affects the tone of the sentence. I therefore generally avoid *till* in technical writing.

Finally - as has already been mentioned - *'til* is a hypercorrection, and is best avoided.

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: This link works for me and the article makes excellent sense to me. I will copy two examples from that article here:  a) He works till 5 p.m. every day. 
_Right_. (Explanation: He works the whole day/ from the reporting time to 5 p.m. and not after that.) b) He works until 5 p.m. every day. (Grammatically **wrong** and makes no sense!) This sentence would work, rather: "He works until it is 5 p.m. every day." (Explanation: He works till the time its 5 p.m. Here, there is no reference of the time-period before 5p.m.)

Comment: BTW, the linked article's conclusion also totally agrees with the example given in @Robusto's answer.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the sentence "He works until 5pm every day", although it might be more idiomatic might be just to say "until 5". Google for phrases like this, you'll find they're standard usage.