# "Till the morning" or "till morning"?

Tags: word-choice, definite-articles, till-until

Which of the following statements is more appropriate?

> 1. You have to stay here till the morning.
> 2. You have to stay here till morning.

The second one seems more fluent to me. What do you think? Please explain what the difference between the two expressions is.

Comment: 2 vs. 3 is a dupe of [What is the difference between “till” and “until”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until)

Comment: Neither is incorrect, go with the more fluent choice.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you "till" a morning.  Seems like, at best, it would lead to a pretty mixed-up day.

Answer (score 2):

They're both completely valid, and I don't think there's any difference in nuance either. But it's worth noting that including **the** is less common, and that both versions have long been less common than [until morning](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=till%20the%20morning,till%20morning,until%20morning&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

[image]

Comment: You left off *til morning* which, on a google search, gets about as many hits as *till morning* (doing a search on *til* gives both *til* and *'til*). *Til* and till together get about 1/2 of the hits as *until* but that isn't surprising since most folks will say *til* / *till* but write *until*. So that doesn't truly tell us anything.

Comment: @AnWulf: I left off *til morning* because in NGram (which is more accurately indexed *published/written* instances) it "flatlined" by comparison with the others. This despite the fact that apostrophes aren't indexed by NGram, so it would have automatically included *'til* anyway. Also note that for their "whole Internet" indexes Google do some odd things. I just checked the top-ranked page for *til morning* - it contains 11 occurences of *till*, but not a single *til*. Indexes into books aren't everything, but they usually mean a lot more than "whole Internet Google".

Comment: It's interesting that the reverse is the case for "till afternoon" and "till the afternoon". The latter is more common.

Comment: @Shoe: That *is* strange. Hundreds of thousands of written instances in Google Books show a consistent ratio over two centuries. With *until* **the** *morning* it's 2:1 in favour of discarding the article, but with *afternoon* it's 2:1 the other way around. That accords with my "inner ear", but I've no real idea why.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ... Did yu put quotes around it? I just did a search on "til morning" and all the results inheld either *til* or *'til* (4.3 mil hits).

Comment: @Shoe ... But *wait til noon* sounds right. Maybe it is owing to *afternoon* is a compound of *after* and *noon*. It seems that once there is another preposition put in, then the *the* is needed.

Comment: @AnWulf: It may well be something to do with an aversion to using two overtly "prepositional" elements consecutively. Not that we *can't* do that, obviously, but perhaps if there's an easy way to avoid it we just grab the opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

"You have stay here" is wrong and should be "You have to stay here" if talking about your obligation, or perhaps "You have stayed here" if talking about the past.

Choose whichever you prefer between "till the morning" and "till morning" (or "until morning" or "until the morning").

Answer (score 1):

> You have stay here till the morning.

is terribly ungrammatical, having nothing to do with till' or 'the' but because it is missing 'to'. IT should be:

> You have to stay here till the morning.

If you want to compare with  your other item:

> You have to stay here till morning.

they are both fine and are virtually identical in meaning.

Comment: I'm intrigued by **virtually** *identical in meaning*. I really can't think of any nuance of difference apart from a faint suggestion that the second version might be slightly more likely to occur as a "txt" message (saves a bit of typing! :)

Comment: @Fumble: I wondered if anyone would catch that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say *wait til the morning*. It may be ok but not for me. *Til morning* rolls off the tung better than *til the morning*.
*Wait til tomorrow*
*Wait til Monday*
The *the* just doesn't belong there. However, *wait til the sun goes down* ... then the *the* is needed. Otherwise, it feels wrong.

Comment: *Till* or *'til*, but not *til*.