# Why is "till" used in this expression: "If we don't leave till after lunch..."?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, conditionals, till-until

> If we don't leave till after lunch we'll be cutting it very fine.

I understand it to mean: "If we don't leave after lunch, we'll be cutting it very fine." (In the event of our not leaving immediately after lunch, we will leave ourselves just enough time to do something.)

But why is *till* in that position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *[till](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/till?q=till)* means *until*

*[Until](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/until?showCookiePolicy=true)* means

> [often preceded by up] in or throughout the period before

In the context of your sentences, the first means

> if we [don't leave in any of the periods before, but] leave [immediately] after lunch, we'll be cutting it fine.

The second sentence means

> If we don't leave [immediately] after lunch, we'll be cutting it very fine.

The first sentence contemplates leaving at a variety of times up to the period immediately following lunch.  The second sentence only contemplates one departure time - immediately following lunch.

Answer (score 1):

Till is the older version of until , as described in another question here:

[What is the difference between "till" and "until"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until)

> Till is indeed older and the two can be used pretty much
>   interchangeably.

As a suggestion, you could also rewrite the sentence like so:

> If we don't leave *'til* after lunch, we'll be cutting it very fine.

*'til* is an abbreviation of 'until'.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It’s also a mistaken answer, since *till* is not an abbreviation or contraction of *until*: spelling it *’til* is a spelling mistake.

Comment: @Tchrist: That seems a somewhat prescriptive/pedantic position to me. Most written instances of [***'Til the morning comes***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22til+the+morning+comes%22+lyrics&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22til+the+morning+comes%22+lyrics&aqs=chrome..69i57.9167385j0j0&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), for example, do include the apostrophe. The fact that there's a separate word ***till*** doesn't somehow "invalidate" using the apostrophised contraction of ***until***.

Comment: I've made my comment more of an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to what @fuzzyanalysis said, my understating of the sentence containing *till* is:

> If we do not leave before lunch is finished, we'll be cutting it very fine.

The subtle difference is that there is no need in interpreting *immediately*.

Also the sentence

> If we don't leave after lunch, we'll be cutting it very fine.

says nothing about *immediately after lunch* or *one hour after lunch* or whatever, just *after lunch*.

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment on the other answer.