# Is it improper to say “count till a hundred”?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, till-until

I'm told that using *count till  a hundred* is improper grammar. What's the correct preposition?

Comment: In Britain we don't count till anything. We count up to....

Comment: In North America you *count to*; *count till* suggests you stop at a certain time rather than a certain number.

Comment: @choster Shop till you drop—count till you… rebound?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'til?

Comment: @MarvMills No, *[till](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/till_1)*. See *[What is the difference between “till” and “until”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989)*

Comment: Well I never! Every day's a school day :)

Comment: @WS2 Some people count till they run out of sheep. :)

Answer (score 6):

*till* is an informal variant of *until*. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/till) says:

> Less formal way of saying [until](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/until).

They both refer to ending at a particular time or event, not a position. So you could say

> Count till you get to 100.

because *you get to 100* is an event. But you wouldn't say

> Count till 100.

because 100 is a number, not a time or event. In that case you would say

> Count to 100.

Comment: Please cite a reference supporting this notion that *till* is somehow “informal” when used as a preposition, a conjunction, or an adverb. The OED says only that it is  *“Characteristically northern in reference to place or purpose (though in ME. occasionally midl. or south.); in reference to time, general Eng. from c 1300, though now often superseded by the compound **until.”***  Even if it is now often superseded, that does not mean it is “informal”, and so I can but wonder why you say that.

Comment: I've added a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Till,is a preposition meaning up to the time of —[image]

Simply *count to....* It is the common usage trend which will not raise any eyebrows.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught to use: 'Count ***to*** 10, 20 etc'.

[Here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/count?q=count%20to) is also an example

'**Count to**' means 'Recite numbers in ascending order'