# Is it awkward to say "to play to / till exhaustion"?

Tags: expressions

I'm trying to translate the Japanese phrase 「遊び疲れる」 which is composed of two verbs, 「遊ぶ」 (to play) and 「疲れる」 (to be exhausted).

Literally, the combined form 「遊び疲れる」 means "to be exhausted due to playing", but I want to keep it as concise as its original Japanese form, which is just two words put together, instead of using that long-winded literal meaning.

That's how I came up with "to play to / till exhaustion", but I'm not 100% confident about whether this is awkward or not. It's fine if it's an obsolete usage of English or if sounds somewhat archaic.

If this is awkward or even grammatically incorrect, what would be an alternative? Please remember to keep it concise, because when that Japanese phrase is used to make a sentence, say, 「彼は遊び疲れた」, it's much less wordy to say:

> He played till exhaustion.
>
> He played to exhaustion.

than:

> He played for such a long time that he was exhausted.
>
> He was exhausted due to a long period of playing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He played to exhaustion

The above mean that the person played *into* exhaustion, which doesn't convey the right meaning.

> He played till exhaustion

This sounds proper with a minor modification.

> He played till/until ***he was exhausted.***

Note that *till* and *until* can be used [interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until)