# Only a matter of time until/till/before

Tags: till-until

What's the right version?

1. It's only a matter of time **until** Paul develops into a great violin player.
2. It's only a matter of time **before** Paul develops into a great violin player.
3. It's only a matter of time **till** Paul develops into a great violin player.

Comment: Note that *till* and *until* mean the same thing. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until?rq=1

Comment: Please look at dictionary meanings before posing such questions. We help those who first try to help themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Both "before" and "until" are correct, but "before" is largely preferred.

[image]

Examples:  [before](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22matter%20of%20time%20before%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [until](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22matter%20of%20time%20until%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

"Til" is very rare in comparison to "until", but that is only in comparison.

[image]

"Til" is very most often spelt "'til".

Examples: [til](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22matter%20of%20time%20til%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)